# how to replace url link if return url like this

Tags: php, string

how to replace URL link if return URL like this
this is code

```
echo "<div id='demo'><a href='$url?title=$title'>$quality</a></br></br></div>";
```

$url return now like this

example

> 123456.xyz.example.com

and i want to change like this

> 123456.xyz.abc.example.com

how can i change it please help me to fix this issue

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For changing `123456.xyz.example.com` to `123456.xyz.abc.example.com`:

```
$a = explode('.', $url);
array_splice($a, 2, 0, array('abc'));
$url = implode('.', $a);
echo "<div id='demo'><a href='$url?title=$title'>$quality</a></br></br></div>";
```

For changing `123456.xyz.example.com` to `123456.xyz.apple.com` change the `array_splice` command to:

```
array_splice($a, 2, 1, array('apple'));
```

And for changing `123456.xyz.example.com` to `123456.xyz.abc.apple.com` change the `array_splice` command to:

```
array_splice($a, 2, 1, array('abc', 'apple'));
```

Comment: suppose i want to change domain name example.com to apple.com how can i change

Comment: thanks but i want to change like this 123456.xyz.abc.apple.com with abc and apple.com togetter

Comment: updated for that as well (would have been good to ask what you want in the question...)

Comment: it is working but after domain dot is coming 123456.xyz.abc.apple.com. like this how can i solve it

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look into the [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function:  and its corresponding function [http_build_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php)

Using the `psrse_url()` function you can split a url into component parts, change any of them, and `http_build_url()` the modified array to get a correctly formed url back

eg:

```
$components = parse_url('http://123456.xyz.example.com/directory/file.php?key=value') ;
$components['hostname'] = '123456.apple.com';
echo $url = http_build_url($components);
```

Comment: but i dont know what is actual url from $url all time it is change but i know what it is starting url link 123456.xyz.example.com